# set a custom input id on the combobox

Tags: fluent-ui, office-ui-fabric-react

Is there a way to set a custom input id on the combobox component?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can pass an id prop on the ComboBox
ex.`<ComboBox id="test"/>`
now its new id will be **test-input**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).